# iOS can't check if object is null

Tags: ios, ios5

So I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)doSomething
{
if (txtName.text != (id)[NSNull null] || txtName.text.length != 0 ) {
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@", txtName.text];
    [lblMessage setText:msg];
}

}
```

`txtName` is an `UITextField`, what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to display some text only when the user types something in the box.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found! `![txtName.text isEqualToString:@""]`

```
- (IBAction)doSomething
{
if (![txtName.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@", txtName.text];
    [lblMessage setText:msg];    

}

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Text in a text field is a `NSString` instance or `nil` value, it is never equal to the instance of `NSNull` class (which is **not the same as nil**). So as 1st comparison is always true then the whole if-condition evaluates to true and message appears.

You could correct your if condition to

```
if (txtName.text != nil && txtName.text.length != 0 )
```

or, as sending length message to the nil will return 0 anyway just have

```
if (txtName.text.length != 0 )
```

although I usually use the 1st option with 2 comparisons

Comment: Are you sure you compiled the changes?

Comment: @Uffo, sorry stupid mistake I made - you must use &&, not || in if condition.

Answer (score 6):

`if (txtName.text != (id)[NSNull null] || txtName.text.length != 0 ) {`

Read it as "If the text is null or the length is not 0"

`txtName.text` is never `nil` (you can just compare against `nil` for a null check, by the way) - the text box always holds *some* text, even if it's empty. So the first disjunct is always true, and the box will always appear.

Comment: And an instance of NSString is never equal to the singleton instance of NSNull.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem like you. This problem relates to NSNull class. And here is my code to check object is null.

```
    NSString* text;
    if([text isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {
           //do something here if that object is null
    }
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Should be `[NSNull null]`

Answer (score 1):

```
#define SAFESTRING(str) ISVALIDSTRING(str) ? str : @""
#define ISVALIDSTRING(str) (str != nil && [str isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] == NO)
#define VALIDSTRING_PREDICATE [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {return (BOOL)ISVALIDSTRING(evaluatedObject);}]
SAFESTRING(PASS_OBJECT OR STRING);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

when value of **myObj** is  **nil** or **< null>**

```
if([myObj isEqual:[NSNull class]] || !myObj) {

// your code

}
```